# Add a math virtual keyboard to the Angular project

Tags: angular, math, keyboard, virtual

I'm creating an Angular application, and I'd like to create a virtual mathematical symbols virtual keyboard to allow users to select the math symbols. Because many math symbols are unavailable from the normal keyboards.
What I want to achieve is like the screenshots below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bZjc.jpg)

Comment: OK, what trouble are you having? What code have you done so far? You haven't explained how we can help you.

Comment: Hi, @Steve I think my issue is I don't know how do I get it started so I haven't started the virtual keyboard yet. I have had the angular project up and running. What I want to do is adding a math symbol virtual keyboard for a input text element in one component. Do you have any idea how to create a virtual keyboard? And how to display the math symbols as buttons in the virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "Custom: Mapped Keys" example on this website: https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/.  I have used this library in the past with good success.  [GitHub project](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard).  There are instructions there for installing using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/virtual-keyboard): `npm i virtual-keyboard`.

Comment: Cool, I have implemented another solution, but the process is similar with your post. Thank you.

Comment: His did you implement this. Kindly share your ideas

Comment: @astroame hello, yes I use this code in production; please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've published a JavaScript library that you can use to create a virtual math keyboard. It is intended for use together with any LaTeX typesetting library (for example MathJax or KaTeX).

GitHub repository: https://github.com/MathKeyboardEngine/MathKeyboardEngine 
Live examples: https://mathkeyboardengine.github.io

My goal was to create an easy-to-use virtual math keyboard library that is highly customizable.